# RestEasy - Jax-rs - Sending custom Object in response body

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, response, resteasy

How do I send my custom object in a response. I just want the values printed from my object.

Lets say I have an object of type `Person`. I am trying to send in REST response body like this.

```
  ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok().entity(personObj);
  return response.build();
```

But I get `500` error.
Tried this one too:

```
  ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(Status.OK).entity(personObj);
  return response.build();
```

Same error.

Tried setting content type as `text/xml`. No use.
What am I missing here? I tried googling. But not many examples out there, especially with the custom objects;

It returns fine, if I just pass a string to `entity()` method.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to return data from a Resteasy resource method you need to do several things depending on what you are trying to return.

- You need to annotate your resource method with the `@Produces`
  annotation to tell Resteasy what the return type of the method should
  be.

  For example, the method below returns XML and JSON depending on what the client asks for in their `Accept` header.

> ```
> @GET
> @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, 
>            MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
> public Response foo()
> {
>      PersonObj obj = new PersonObj();
>
>      //Do something...
>      return Response.ok().entity(obj).build();
> }
> ```

Resteasy supports marshalling the following datatypes by default:

[image]

If the datatypes you wish to support are in this table then that
   means they are supported by JAXB and all you need to do is annotate
   your `PersonObj` class with JAXB annotations to tell it how to
   marshall and unmarshall the object.

> ```
> @XmlRootElement
> @XmlType(propOrder = {"firstName", "lastName"})
> public class PersonObj
> {
>   private String firstName;
>   private String lastName;
>
>   //Getters and Setters Removed For Brevity
> }
> ```

---

### What if your content-type is not supported out of the box?

If you have a custom content-type that you would like to marshall then you need to create a `MessageBodyWriter` implementation that will tell Resteasy how to marshall the type.

```
Provider
@Produces({"application/x-mycustomtype"})
public class MyCustomTypeMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter {

}
```

Just implement the interface and register it like any other Provider.

If you would like to read a custom content-type then you need to implement a custom `MessageBodyReader` to handle the incoming type and add it to the `@Consumes` annotation on your receiving method.