# How can I have myObject from Response Object

Tags: java, junit

I have a resource which I would like to test. To do that, I want to extract myObject from javax.ws.rs.core.Response. How can I do that?

The resource looks like this:

```
@Post
@Path("/test")
public MyObjectClass myresource(){return myObject}
```

My test:

```
@Test
public void test(){
Response response = resources.getJersyTest()
    .target("/test")
    .request()
    .post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.json(String.class));

assertThat...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not a good idea to return custom object from Rest resource. You may reconsider to use one of standard formats JSON or XML and return a Response instead of `MyObjectClass`. also you need to take either request or String (or both) as parameter(s) to the resource method to work with what you posts in request.

As example:

```
@Post
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myresource(@Context HttpServletRequest request, String postedBody){
   MyObjectClass myObject = new MyObjectClass();
   // ... set myObject properties ...
   return Response.status(200).entity(myObject).build();
}
```

Of course for JSON your `MyObjectClass` must be annotated for JSON...
Then in your response on client side you will have JSON representation of your `myObject` in the `response.getEntity` and it can be unmarshalled back to MyObjectClass.

but if you still want to return your custom object you have to create a mechanism to marshal/unmarshal your object on both sides.

Check this answer for it [RestEasy - Jax-rs - Sending custom Object in response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17533280/resteasy-jax-rs-sending-custom-object-in-response-body)

From other hands in the unit test you can call your resource method directly and just cast result.

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution, just specify the type of the response in the function post:

```
@Test
public void test(){
MyObjectClass response = resources.getJersyTest()
    .target("/test")
    .request()
    .post(javax.ws.rs.client.Entity.json(String.class), MyObjectClass.class);
assertThat(...
}
```